# Lost access to Facebook Instant Article Audience Network App

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-audience-network, facebook-instant-articles

I've lost access to my Instant Article Audience Network App. The developer who managed the App lost his account while I was not an admin of the App. Instant article is running fine and perfect but the placement id integrated is old one which I've no access right now.

Is there any way to change/replace the Audience Network App and continue monetizing with new placement ID.

or any way to recover the old App

Please help

(Im the administer of the page and linked website )

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming questions, within the scope of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @rwp, The question is how to change Audience Network App for Instant Article of a page I administrate. Hope, that is technical

Comment: No it is not technical. You need to reach out to Facebook have them fix it for you

Comment: The problem is I can't find a link to contact Facebook for this issue. After I submitted the issue to the grievance_officer, just got system replay "this mailbox isn't monitored"
Now, Just posted this to fb community page and waiting.
If any of you know better way to contact please help

Comment: did you find a solution? i have the same problem

Comment: @AryehArmon Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.